# Some "Product" of Positive Definite Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I could remember that if $A,B$ are two positive definite matrices, then $(a_{ij}b_{ij})$ is positive definite also. But I could not see how to prove it then.

Comment: What is $(a_{ij}b_{ij})$?

Comment: Have a look on the [Schur product theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_product_theorem).

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Following the remark of user126154, I suppose here that the two matrix $A$ and $B$ are symmetric.

Let $x=(x_1,\cdots,x_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n=E$ and put $q_A(x)=\sum_{i,j}a_{i,j}x_ix_j$. As $A$ is positive definite, there exists $n$ independant linear forms $\displaystyle T_k(x)=\sum_{l=1}^n \alpha_{k,l}x_l$ such that $\displaystyle q_A(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n (T_k(x))^2$. Hence you get that $a_{i,j}=\sum \alpha_{k,i}\alpha_{k,j}$.

Hence, if you put $y_k=(\alpha_{k,i}x_i, i=1,\cdots,n)$:
$$q(x)=\sum_{i,j}b_{i,j}a_{i,j}x_ix_j=\sum_{i,j,k}b_{i,j}\alpha_{k,i}\alpha_{k,j}x_ix_j
=\sum_{i,j,k}b_{i,j}(\alpha_{k,i}x_i)(\alpha_{k,j}x_j)=\sum_{k}q_B(y_k)$$

You have hence $q(x)\geq 0$ for all $x$; if $q(x)=0$, you get $q_B(y_k)=0$ for all $k$, hence $y_k=0$ for all $k$, and $T_l(x)=0$ for all $l$; as the $T_l$, $1\leq l\leq n$ are independant, this show that $x=0$.

Comment: Well, there is hidden that the two matrices must be symmetric, because if $A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & -5\\5&1\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$, then both have a positive definite quadratic form, but the "product term by term" is not positive definite.